# Permission Denied when start the Redis in docker from Windows OS

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis, dockerfile

Can anyone please explain what is the issue here and how to resolve that?

While I try to start the redis in docker desktop from windows OS, it always returning the error ""redis-redis-1 | 1:M 21 Jun 2022 14:40:59.452 # Can't open the append-only file: Permission denied

Here is my dockercompose file,

```
version: '2'
services:
  redis:
    image: 'docker.io/bitnami/redis:6.0-debian-10'
    environment:
      # ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD is recommended only for development.
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - REDIS_DISABLE_COMMANDS=FLUSHDB,FLUSHALL
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    volumes:
      - '/home/vagrant/var/Redis:/bitnami/redis/data'
```

The second image is the files from the redis-data folder.

[image: Folder Architecture]

[image: Within redis-data folder]

Comment: Is this path `/home/vagrant/var/Redis` on your windows machine?

Comment: No. What path I need to give in windows instead of that?

Comment: Are you trying to map that redis_data folder to `/bitnami/redis/data`? Try `/e/...path_to.../redis_data:/bitnami/redis/data` e being the drive letter of the partition on which the redis_data folder exists.

Comment: you can also try a relative path as in `./redis_data/:/bitnami/redis/data/`

Comment: Alright, let me write it as the answer so you can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your docker-compose file, change the line:

`'/home/vagrant/var/Redis:/bitnami/redis/data'`

to

`./redis_data/:/bitnami/redis/data/`

Since redis_data is the folder you are trying to mount to the container.